# The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using pyspark on databricks and trying to iterate over a small dataframe (50 rows) using a **while** loop until the **dataframe count is 0** and do some basic manipulations inside the loop (filter, sort, get first row and  update some columns) and I get the following error after 15 iterations or so

**The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting.**

After research I found out it's a memory problem.

I'm not using **toPandas()** or **collect()**, I'm not using many objects (only 3 dataframes inside the loop and I update them in each iteration), I run the notebook while nothing else is running on the cluster, I tried to increase the driver's memory but I still get the same error.
I also tried using **gc.collect()** and **spark.catalog.clearCache()** but nothing worked.

The code is something like this:

```
# df1 and df2 read from the database

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

df3 = df1.filter((df1.col2 > 0) & (df1.col3 >= 0))

while df3.count() > 0:

  data = []
  new_data = ['', 0, '']

  df3 = df3.orderBy(df3.col1.asc(), df3.col2.asc())

  df_first = df3.first()

  a = df_first['col1']
  b = df_first['col2']
  c = df_first['col3']

  new_data[0] = a
  new_data[1] = b
  new_data[2] = c

  data.append(tuple(new_data))

  new_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
  df2 = df2.union(new_df)

  df1 = (df1.withColumn('col2', 
                              when(df1['col1'] == a, df1['col2'] + b)
                              .otherwise(df1['col2'])
                       )
        )

  df3 = (df3.withColumn('col2', 
                              when(df3['col1'] == a, df3['col2'] + b)
                              .otherwise(df3['col2'])
                       )
        )

  df1 = df1.withColumn('col3', df1['col2'] - df1['col4'] - df1['col5'])
  df3 = df3.withColumn('col3', df3['col2'] - df3['col4'] - df3['col5'])

  df3 = df3.filter((df3.col2 > 0) & (df3.col3 >= 0))
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: How large is df1 and df2?

Comment: Thank you @BhanunagasaiVamsi-MT I'm using a cluster with standard type but I tried adding the command **spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.parquet.nativeReader.enabled", False)** and changed the worker type as mentioned but I still have the same issue.
However, they mention in the link you send that this is the reason for this issue
**This issue occurs due the fact that JVMs reuse the memory locations too many times and start misbehaving**. But I really don't know what other approach can be followed instead of reassigning a value to the same objects.

Comment: @PhuriChal df1 has 48 rows and 29 columns while df2 has 10 rows and 15 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by converting my data frames from pyspark to pandas before the loop and then converting them again to pyspark after the loop.

Turns out you can't use pyspark inside a loop and reassign its value every time, you will get memory issues.